# How to render a ctools content type programmatically?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I have a ctools plugin aka. content-type aka. panel pane. How does one render it programmatically ?

Comment: +1, very interesting question. I'm wondering though, can a ctools plugin be rendered outside of a page manager page? Since that would be void of a context, does rendering e content type still make sense?

Comment: Using contexts is not mandatory. Also , forcing a context manually is always an option. Like here - https://gist.github.com/3076130

Answer (score 4):

[`ctools_content_render()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!content.inc/function/ctools_content_render/7) is the solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this would work?   I'm reading the docs and trying things but not getting anywhere

Comment: Depending on where you call ctools_content_render(), you may also need to bring the ctools code into scope, otherwise you'll get fatal errors. This can be achieved with  "module_load_include("inc", "ctools", "includes/content");"

Comment: Do not forget to include `ctools_include('content');` before `ctools_content_render()`, because in other case you will get fatal error.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great and simple example on how to do this in the `ctools_ajax_sample` module (in the CTools suite).

As it has been pointed out, the key is to use the function [`ctools_content_render()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!content.inc/function/ctools_content_render/7).

The example shows how to populate the arguments of the function, although you obviously have to customize it according to your needs.

[This thread](https://groups.drupal.org/node/37104#comment-1020478) in Drupal Groups gives more insight on how to load the right context.

File `ctools/ctools_ajax_sample/ctools_ajax_sample.module`

```
function ctools_ajax_simple_form() {
  ctools_include('content');
  ctools_include('context');
  $node = node_load(1);
  $context = ctools_context_create('node', $node);
  $context = array('context_node_1' => $context);
  return ctools_content_render('node_comment_form', 'node_comment_form', ctools_ajax_simple_form_pane(), array(), array(), $context);
}

function ctools_ajax_simple_form_pane() {
  $configuration = array(
    'anon_links' => 0,
    'context' => 'context_node_1',
    'override_title' => 0,
    'override_title_text' => '',
  );
  return $configuration;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you load the required file, all you really need to do, is to call the render function (`hook_content_type_render`) which will return a standard class object, much like `hook_block_view` does.
All you need from there is a theme function, unless you just want to render the raw output directly.

In code it could look something like this:

```
function render_ctools_content($subtype, $conf, $panel_args, $context, $function, $file, $theme = TRUE) {
  require_once $file;
  $pane = new stdClass();
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $pane = $function($subtype, $conf, $panel_args, $context); // hook_content_type_render
  }
  if ($theme) {
    return theme('module_ctools_content', array('pane' => $pane));
  }
  return $pane->content;
}
```

Comment: thank's for your reply. Calling the render func directly is, of course, the obvious choice. But this solution feels more like a hack. I am looking for something along the lines of "ctools_render_ctype('ctype_name')" :)

Comment: @roGi That function doesn't exist, what I've shown above is the gist of how it would look like, but it probably won't be feasible to make something as simple as you suggest, since ctools content types aren't that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull a panelized page in panopoly using the following code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'page_manager', 'plugins/tasks/node_view');
$node = node_load($nid);
$render = page_manager_node_view_page($node);
echo drupal_render($render);
```

Comment: By including plugin file with `module_load_include()` you may break ctools plugins loading process. CTools uses `require_once` method, so if file was included previously by thirdparty script it will be not possible to include it by ctools (and parse `$plugin` array). So as a resullt your pane will not work in other places.